# Heroku can't precompile or clean assets uninitialized constant Rake::AltSystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm having trouble getting my assets to precompile on heroku.

I think the issue is related to a file that changed type (it was sym link, then a hardlink, and now just a normal file).

When precompiling when I deploy I get:

```
rake aborted!
       File to import not found or unreadable: token-input.
       Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/tmp/build_3f056915-63fa-4ec6-973d-39b8dd847458/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)
...
```

(token input is the file I suspected, so am trying to clean as per [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844955/heroku-assets-precompile)

But when I do a rake:assets clean I get this error.

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::AltSystem
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:68:in `rake_system'
...
```

I'm pretty stumped on this error - I googled it, very little came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was more symlinks. The error message refers to the CSS that goes with token-input, which I'd  forgotten goes with the javascript file.
(When posting, I had assumed it was a javascript file error, which was why I was confused)

I changed the CSS files from symlinks to normal files, pushed to heroku and it all went smoothly.

Moral of the story, don't use symlinks in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add token-input to asset paths.

I would try this:

1. enter `rails console`
2. `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`
3. Check whether token-input is inside these directories.
4. If not, in `config/application.rb`:

   ```
   config.assets.path << Rails.root.join("path","to","token-input-folder")
   ```

Comment: The file is in `lib/assets/javascripts/` (which is present in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` and there are two other javascript assets in there that don't seem to have a problem.