# Rails apps Destroy/Delete method is not working on Heroku, but works in local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku

I just created new a rails app and ran this scaffold command:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string age:integer
```

Then i ran:

`rake db:migrate` command.

I uploaded it to github and from it to heroku. However `Destroy` method works in me local machine but on heroku when I click to to destroy link it goes to show method and show the data(user).

I am using ubuntu 14.04(on windows 7), rails 3.2.7, ruby 1.9.3.

[The app link on github](https://github.com/junan/haha)

Comment: Rails links with the `:delete` method need Javascript. Did you check that the Javascript files can be loaded from Heroku?

Comment: Don't know how to check it. I just deployed the app from the github by this command   "git push heroku master" @spickermann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `precompile` before deploy on heroku as the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile
```

Read more from [Precompiling Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), [Heroku Assets Precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844955/heroku-assets-precompile)

Answer (score 1):

Go to config/environments/production.rb and change

```
 config.assets.compile = false
```

To

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

If it is set to true then Rails will try to find a Javascript or CSS file by first looking in the public/assets directory.
Or you can try this

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile
```